# nested linked list in c

Tags: c, printing, linked-list

I created a linked list in C, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define data(LINKED_LIST) ((LINKED_LIST)->data)
#define rest(LINKED_LIST) ((LINKED_LIST)->rest)

typedef struct LINKED_LIST {
    void * data ;
    struct LINKED_LIST * rest ;
} * list ;

list node(void *, const list) ;
void print_ll(list L) ;

int main(){
    list lst = NULL ;
    char a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd', e = 'e';

    lst = node(&a, *(list*)node( node(&b, node(&c, NULL) ), node(&d, node(&e, NULL) ) ) );

    print_ll(lst);
    return 0;
}

list node(void * d, const list L){
    list Node = malloc(sizeof(struct LINKED_LIST)) ;
    data(Node) = d ; // Node -> data = d ;
    rest(Node) = L ; // Node -> rest = L ;
    return Node ; 
}

void print_ll(list L){
    printf("\n( ");
    for(; L != NULL; L=rest(L)){
        printf("%c ", *(char *)data(L));
    }
    printf(") \n");
}
```

I would like to print all the elements of this linked list.

For example :  for this list  `lst = node(&a, *(list*)node( node(&b, node(&c, NULL) ), node(&d, node(&e, NULL) ) ) );`

I would like to have : `(a (b c) d e)`

instead the output is `(a b c)`.

Comment: Where  is there defined nil?

Comment: also when you are printing *data is simply being cast to char * and you are not going "down the list" anywhere (you are missing the functionality for that, and your design would have to be tweaked)

Comment: Hint: don't hide pointers behind typedefs, it only causes confusion. Also I'm pretty sure that macros like `data` and `rest` cause more harm than good.  And why `rest`?? Shouldn't it rather be `next`?